# ubuntu 11.04 hangs at purple screen

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, boot-failure

I used to use Ubuntu with no issues.

Since today, it just hangs at the purple screen forever. Also I couldn't try recovery mode as my keyboard doesn't work when I am shown the recovery options menu. I am not able to select an option.

Info : DELL Inspiron, Ubuntu 11.04, Windows 7

Comment: Try pressing Esc (Escape)when you see the purple screen. If that doesn't help, try F2. If you get any messages, regarding your problem, please reply with the output of these messages.

Comment: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable:usr.bin.firefox            * Starting AppArmor Profiles.    And it hangs there. Thanks for helping out @mitch

Comment: Try deleting /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.bin.firefox.

Comment: @mitch Sorry, I am bit new to Ubuntu. How can I get sudo access to terminal to delete that file when i am not even logged in. Really appreciate your effort to help me out

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
gksudo nautilus
```

Browse, to the correct folder, and delete the file.

Comment: No luck. When I press ctrl + alt + T just when the purple screen with ubuntu logo is about to come, it shows me the same screen that I get if I press ESC or F2. But earlier it used to stop at 'Starting AppArmor profiles' but now it went beyond that and stopped at 'Starting deferred execution scheduler' @Mitch

Comment: Can you do Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Comment: no luck. the entire screen goes blank :(. Btw I think some of the recovery options like dpkg - to repair broken packages - might do the trick.I can select the recovery mode in the grub menu with my keyboard but then I see purple screen with Recovery Menu with all the options but I am not able to select any of them with my keyboard. No key is working, even I cant turn on capslock. Do you have any idea @Mitch

Answer (score 0):

reboot the system and choose 'rescue a broken system' then follow on screen steps and then you can delete that file while you have access to a root shell.